# android camera2 get nv21 byte array from preview image

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm trying to get the black and white values (the Y-plane) from the preview frame in the camera2 API. This is what I have so far:

```
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader, reader) {
   Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
   Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
   ByteBuffer yPlane = planes[0].getBuffer();
   if (firstRun) {
      ySize = yPlane.remaining();
      nv21 = new byte[ySize];
   }
   yPlane.get(nv21, 0, ySize);
   Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(nv21.length) + " " + String.valueOf(nv21[0]));
   image.close();
}
```

However, the length of the array is not as expected (1280*960=1 228 800, nv21.length returns 12 979 200) and nv21[0] gives random values.
What Am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please include the code for how you're creating your ImageReader.  Is it in the YUV_420_888 format?

Comment: imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight(), ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 3);
        imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(onImageAvailableListener, backgroundHandler);

Answer (score 0):

The size of buffer doesn't have to be exactly 1280*960, since there can be [row stride](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image.Plane.html#getRowStride()) between each row of pixels.  That said, a 10x difference in total size seems surprising, but not infeasible - check what the value is.

I'd recommend trying to actually draw the Y plane into an ImageView (for debugging this doesn't need to be efficient, so you can just use a Bitmap and a Canvas and drawColor), to see what it looks like.  Is it just complete garbage, or is it a real Y plane with weird padding, etc?

Comment: The rowStride is equal to 4160 in my case, but I'm not sure if I fully understood the concept of row/line striding. Does it mean that the first row of my image is represented in elements 0-959, and the second row from element 960+4160 to element 1919+4160? Because, in that case, the total length of my Y-array is still too long: 12 979 200 - (1280*4160) = 7 654 400 and not 1 228 800 (= 1280*960).

Comment: no, row Y starts at location rowStride*Y and ends at location rowStride*Y+width-1, so the whole buffer size would be (rowStride * (height - 1) + width) = 4160 * 959 + 1280 = 3990720, which is still far less than the buffer size you're seeing. (The last row doesn't include the row padding because there's no reason to include it)  I'd still check if that first 4 MB of data is a valid Y plane and just ignore the rest, but it certainly shouldn't normally be doing that. You could also try to decode it with BitmapFactory to see if somehow it's a JPEG.